# Can I change GCE VM MAC?

Tags: google-compute-engine

We have a software application mapped to certain mac address. I want to install the application on GCE VM, but I need to change the VM MAC address. Is it possible to change Google compute engine VM MAC address?

Answer (score 1):

No, the GCE API does not make MAC address configurable.